# UITextField limit digits after period ","

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextfield

I have a UITextField in which you can enter only numbers and period "," 
This is how it's made:

```
#define NUMBERS @"0123456789"
#define NUMBERSPERIOD   @"0123456789,"

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

NSCharacterSet *cs;
NSString *filtered;

// Check for period
if ([textFieled.text rangeOfString:@","].location == NSNotFound) {

    cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:NUMBERSPERIOD] invertedSet];
    filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
}

// Period is in use
cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:NUMBERS] invertedSet];
filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

return [string isEqualToString:filtered];

}
```

Now I want to limit the digits entered after "," to just 2. I'm not sure how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int positionOfPeriod = [filtered rangeOfString:@","].location;
filtered = [filtered substringToIndex: MIN(positionOfPeriod+3, [filtered length])];
```

Comment: @trojanfoe just recognized the first difference to my line ^^

Comment: It's horrid code anyway; there is no need to use `stringByAppendingString` as you know the length anyway (why not just use `subStringWithRange`?)

Comment: @trojanfoe you're right. I just wanted to provide him with a starting point, also stated that it wasn't an elegant/efficient solution. Now thought about it again. Hope this solution is better.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I got an error: [__NSCFString substringToIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds. Can you please explain with a little more details how to implement your code?

Comment: @maxus182 It must be MIN not MAX, please try again. Idea is, that you know the position of the ",". Now you create a substring, which includes the next to characters after the ",". You'll need the MIN, else there will be a out of bounds exception if there is no or only one character after the ",".

Comment: The code is working now but unfortunately it does not limit decimals to 2. Maybe the problem is in my part of code?

Comment: @maxus182 I changed the +2 to +3. I checked it. filtered String only has to characters after the `,`. Pasting the two lines before the return should work. What's the problem now?